# React router does not change view, but url is changed - App is load inside iframe

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have react app loaded inside iframe. 
this is routing part:

```js
<Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={View} />
      <Route path="/create" component={CreateNewItemPage} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

and I use Links inside View.js to navigate:

```js
<Button
     variant="contained"
     color="primary"
     component={Link} 
     to="/create">
 Create
</Button>
```

Problem is that on click url is changed but view is not changing.
Maybe problem is that it's in iframe not sure. I faced this issue first time.
Tried 'exact' attribute for Route, but same issue.
Also there is no any error in browser console.

Comment: Please Wrap Your Button between `Link` Component , May Help's You

Comment: I tried that too, but same. @sinafarhadi

Comment: its in react native ?

Comment: no, not react native

Comment: can you share your components code too. i think you are not returning jsx or not importing React

Comment: did you solve this? I am rendering a react app inside an iframe and the router is not updated when I change the iframe's url

Answer (score 0):

The reason might the lack of passing history to Router.
[Check Router for more information](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router)

Example from Docs:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

const customHistory = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(<Router history={customHistory} />, node);
```

You could try `<BrowserRouter>` instead. BrowserRouter is nothing more than the Router with the HTML5 history API. [Check BrowserRouter for more info](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter)

I hope it fixes your issue. Have a great day.